# SOCKS proxy on a local network

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, putty, socks

I have a Windows 7 machine that I use to open up a SOCKS connection using Putty on SSH. I set the tunnel to Dynamic localhost 8080 which I can use locally.

How do I get a machine on the local network to access and able to use that proxy?

Under FireFox settings for network on the SOCKS settings I tried and entered 192.166.2.2:8080 for the local computer that has the open connection. Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the checkbox "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" in PuTTY's Tunnel settings:

[image: Screenshot PuTTY]

Answer (score 0):

on your server run powershell as admin and run

```
 netstat -abo | findstr LISTENING | findstr :8080
```

note the IP address associated with `:8080`. is it `127.0.0.1, 192.168.2.2,`or`0.0.0.0`?
My hunch is the ip address is `127.0.0.1`, which means that the port is only available to the localhost. try adjusting your socks proxy to use `192.168.2.2` instead of `'localhost'`.